# Joining more tables while using different joins

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I have 3 tables that I need to join to get my data and the Table1  in the query should be the one I  use to "left join" the two other tables to. My concern is, to what table is the second join related to in the sequence and how it goes further if I join even more tables. Code example:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d
  FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2 ON T1.a=T2.a
  LEFT JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.a=T3.a
```

I believe that it works the way that the join is related to the table I specify in the ON clause, i.e. by stating:

```
LEFT JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.a=T3.a
```

However, I am not sure and therefore I ask if anybody can help me better understand how multiple joins work. Thanks!

Comment: You can join Table3 to either Table1 or Table2, SQL doesn't mind. Remember to use the table alias in your select statement though (e.g. SELECT T1.a, T1.b, T2.c, T3.d)

Comment: In addition to @RichBenner comment, you can also `JOIN` `Table3` on to both `Table1` and `Table2`. E.g. `LEFT JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.a = T3.a AND T2.b = T3.b`

Comment: Thank you both for the comments! BeaglesEnd, could you explain me on an example why would I need to join on both? Is it for instance when I want to find matches for both tables and not just one?

Comment: might be helpful http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: Thanks! will take a look at it